# How to save multiple rows of data by looping through an array or a map?

Tags: grails, groovy

```
Class Buyer {
   String name
   static constraints = {
   }
}
Class Order {
    String ref
    static belongsTo = [buyer:Buyer]
    static constraints = {
    buyer(nullable:false)
    }
}
```

In  OrderController.groovy

```
...
def someAction = {
  //working
  def data1 = ["buyer.id": 2, "ref": "xyz"]
  def ord = new Order(data1);
  ord.save();

  def data2 = ["buyer.id": 2, "ref": "234xyz"]
  def ord2 = new Order(data2);
  ord2.save();


  //But in a loop - its not working
  def items = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
  def data2 = [:]
  for(e in items) {
     data2 = ["buyer.id": 2, "ref" : e.value] //keeping buyer id same
     def ord = new Order(data2);
     ord.save();
     data2 = [:] //just emptying it?
  }
}
```

As you would notice in "working" above, if I am able to save multiple rows by copy pasting and definging new maps but If I try to loop through an array, it doesnt work. Any ideas how do I save data by looping through an array or a map?

Any questions, please let know
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm not sure about `["buyer.id": 2, "ref" : e.value]`,  I think it should be `[buyer: Buyer.get(2), ref : e.value]`.

Second, I would recommend using [cascading save](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) to do the task. You can try something like this(You need to define a `static hasMany = [orders: Order]` relation in Buyer for Buyer-Order relationship.

```
Buyer b = new Buyer(name: "foo")
for(e in items) {
     def ord = new Order(ref: e.value);
     b.addToOrders(ord)
  }

b.save(flush:true)
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. I had tried .get() but somehow it didnt work. I need to try ur solution and i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: why did you use Buyer b = new Buyer(name: "foo") instead of def b = new Buyer(name : "foo") ??

Comment: @Wbdvlpr: def b = new Buyer is ok. I don't understand why Buyer.get(buyerId) fails, is it still provide the same result or it fails to get the Buyer?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do:

```
def someAction = {
  def items = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
  items.each { item ->
     def ord = new Order( [ 'buyer.id':2, ref:item ] )
     ord.save()
  }
}
```

What errors (if any) are you getting?

Also, why are you doing `e.value`?  This will get you an array of Character rather than a String (which is what your first working example is using)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tim, isn't this solution somewhat similar to mine except u r using "each"?

Comment: Yeah, and not using `e.value` and ommiting the unnecessary semi colons and not clearing the map (which there is no reason to do)

Comment: hmm .. i m very new to groovy and as i was stuck i tried various options like emptying map etc to get it sorted. I need to try and see how it goes? also how do I get error message is it .save(failOnError:true) ??